# How do I install a cx8800 TV tuner's firmware?

Tags: hardware, tv-tuner, firmware

The cx8800 TV tuner is supported in the kernel but when computer starts it says that firmware is not found. There is an unofficial firmware that can be downloaded and copied into `/lib/firmware` to make the card work. Should I report this missing file as a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firmware blobs (including the ones for tv tuner cards) typically live in the `linux-firmware-nonfree` package

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

I don't see anything for a CX8800 in the file, but it might be worth installing it and seeing one of the firmware files in there support your tuner. If not you can [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware-nonfree/+filebug) on the package.

Comment: It works. There is a file called xc3028-v27.fw. Looks like this firmware file is used for many cx**** tuners.